# How to increase the count value in server after clicking the button in android

Tags: java, android, http, post, get

In my server side part some prayer side counting is there,now i fetched and display in android.Now i am giving an button in android,after clicking the button,that countvalue has to been increasing.After clicking the button once,their count value has to increase for that we have to use and httpget method to increase an count value in JSON.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FetchDataListener,OnClickListener {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    ListView lv;
    private List<Application> items;
    private Button btnGetSelected;
    private Button praycount;

    //private ProjectsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    //private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);  
        //mDbHelper = new ProjectsDbAdapter(this);
        //mDbHelper.open();
        //fillData();
        //registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        praycount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pray);

     lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
            mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); 
        return true;
    }
```

I need after clicking the pray button how to increase the count value,  i have to send an count value in this url "http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/posts/id.json"

If i will click the button,it has to reflect in server side also.it has to increase the count value in server side.

Comment: The given URL is unreachable, and I think you should post the codes on `FetchDataTask`, if there is anything you need to get from the calling URL, the `FetchDataTask` is where you should code.

Comment: @ChorWaiChun, dude for fetchDatatask i am using as get method for server side to our android(client side),but now we have to do from client to server side,after clicking the button it has to increase the count